# Что не так с SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl, std

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _main в функции "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

Использовал код из туториала для SDL, но все равно выдает эту ошибку.
Помогите вообщем xD

---

```cpp
/*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2020)
and may not be redistributed without written permission.*/

//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

            //Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

            //Wait two seconds
            SDL_Delay( 2000 );
        }
    }

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что sdl переопределяет `main` макросом, а затем вызвает его из собственной реализации настоящей `main`. Необходмо прилинковать `SDL2main` содержащую ее.

Comment: Окей, а как с этим разобраться? xD