# Компиляция программы на основе библиотеки SDL в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl2, sdl

Решился взяться за изучение первой граф библиотеки SDL но во время набора кода увидел одну странность :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<SDL.h>


int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Peremoga", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 400, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 100, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(3000);
    return 0;
}
```

программа корректно работает только если  функция main берёт переменные как показано в коде,хотел бы узнать почему так и можно ли что то с этим сделать,и ещё хотелось бы получить пример где создание окна вынесено в отдельную функцию.Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы бы лучше привели пример кода, который не работает, и написали, какая там возникает проблема, и почему вам понадобился такой код. А то совершенно непонятно почему вам обязательно хочется с этим что-то сделать.

Comment: Вот вариант кода который не хочет компилироваться (по крайней мере в VS19),я хочу знать почему мэйну нужно подавать какие то даже пустые значения чтобы код компилировался

Comment: Приведенный код без проблем компилируется в VS2019. Если он не компилируется у вас, то необходимо привести лог сборки.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Скопировать текст лога сборки в вопрос. Но на самом деле я подозреваю, что у вас конфуз с SDLmain https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1081627/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81-sdl2

Comment: Как можно прилинковать SDL2main ?

Comment: Source.cpp
SDL2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_main referenced in function _main_getcmdline
C:\Users\Олег\source\repos\Project7\Debug\Project7.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   (текст лога сборки)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123322/discussion-between-marshalstroheim-and-user7860670).

Comment: Если вы используете SDLmain, то у функции main следует правильно указывать параметры, иначе это получится не та перегрузка, которая будет вызываться из настоящей функция main в SDL.